# How to check loaded bytes of a web page in real-time using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web page that loads several resource when launched. I want to notify user about the loaded bytes while the page is loading using a progress bar.

I use the following code to determine loaded bytes:

```
var totalBytes = 12295985; //to simplify matters, I enter this value manually
var loadedBytes = 0;
const observer = new PerformanceObserver((list) => {
    list.getEntries().forEach((entry) => {
         loadedBytes += entry.transferSize;
         console.log('loaded: ' + loadedBytes + 'bytes');
    });
});
observer.observe({
    type: "resource",
    buffered: true
});
```

The above code works fine but it updates after each resource is loaded. Since there are some large resources in my web page (like large webgl 3D files), it pauses to update for several seconds during initial loading. I want to be able to monitor loading process every second. Is there any method to see loaded bytes of a webpage in real-time?

Comment: You should use the observer in a worker that reads the performance entries every second. Might get the same effect though.